# SVG elements appears in DOM but are invisible on screen

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I try to draw a stave with SVG using [Vexflow](http://www.vexflow.com) and [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com) and when I load the page the SVG elements appear in the DOM but they don't appear on the screen.

I checked if there is any CSS rule which could hide the elements, but there isn't any..
Also checked on different browsers, different lib versions, nothing...

Here is the SVG appearing in the DOM :

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fermata</title>

    <!-- Raphael.js -->
    <script src="../deps/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>

    <!-- VexFlow Uncompiled Sources -->
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/header.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/vex.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/flow.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/fraction.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/fonts/vexflow_font.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/glyph.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tables.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stave.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/staveconnector.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tabstave.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/voice.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/voicegroup.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/modifier.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/modifiercontext.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/accidental.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/dot.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tickcontext.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tickable.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/note.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/bend.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stavenote.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tabnote.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/barnote.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/ghostnote.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/formatter.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stavetie.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stavehairpin.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tabtie.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tabslide.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/beam.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/vibrato.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/annotation.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tuning.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stavemodifier.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/keysignature.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/timesignature.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/clef.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/music.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/keymanager.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/renderer.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stavebarline.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stavevolta.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/staverepetition.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stavesection.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stavetempo.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/articulation.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tremolo.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/raphaelcontext.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/tuplet.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/boundingbox.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/textnote.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/strokes.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/stringnumber.js"></script>
    <script src="../deps/vexflow/src/frethandfinger.js"></script>

    <!-- Fermat srcs -->
    <script src="../src/Fermata.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Utils.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Data.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Mapping.Clef.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Mapping.Direction.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Mapping.Connector.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Mapping.Barline.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.Call.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.SymbolSize.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.NoteStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.NoteType.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.SoundType.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.PitchPitched.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.PitchRest.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.PitchUnpitched.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.NoteConverter.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.TieRenderer.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.GraceNote.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.CueNote.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.NormalNote.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.Note.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.RenderAttribute.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.Direction.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.Barline.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.Backup.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.PartList.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.Header.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Render.Score.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Drawer.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/Fermata.Drawer.Score.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-score">
        <canvas id="canvas-score" width="1700px" height="250">
            <svg style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" height="150" version="1.1" width="1700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.0</desc>
                <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs>
                <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" x="20" y="40" width="0" height="0.5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" font="10pt Arial"></rect>
                <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" x="20" y="50" width="0" height="0.5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" font="10pt Arial"></rect>
                <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" x="20" y="60" width="0" height="0.5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" font="10pt Arial"></rect>
                <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" x="20" y="70" width="0" height="0.5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" font="10pt Arial"></rect>
                <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" x="20" y="80" width="0" height="0.5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" font="10pt Arial"></rect>
                <path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M25,70M39.0544,26.8288C39.112,26.800000000000004,39.1696,26.800000000000004,39.256,26.800000000000004C39.6016,26.800000000000004,40.0048,27.088,40.580799999999996,27.808C42.9136,30.486400000000003,44.5552,35.152,44.5552,38.9536C44.5552,39.241600000000005,44.4976,39.472,44.4976,39.760000000000005C44.2384,44.2816,42.3952,47.9968,38.7376,51.510400000000004L37.7584,52.4608L37.4128,52.8352L37.4128,52.9504L37.6144,53.8144L37.931200000000004,55.3696L38.248,56.8096C38.68,58.768,38.8528,59.775999999999996,38.8528,59.775999999999996C38.8528,59.775999999999996,38.8528,59.775999999999996,38.8528,59.775999999999996C38.8528,59.775999999999996,38.968,59.775999999999996,39.112,59.7472C39.256,59.7472,39.7168,59.6896,40.2064,59.6896C40.552,59.6896,40.8976,59.7472,41.0704,59.7472C45.1312,60.2656,48.270399999999995,63.1744,49.1632,67.264C49.336,67.9264,49.3936,68.6464,49.3936,69.3664C49.3936,73.2544,47.0608,76.9696,43.172799999999995,78.7264C42.9424,78.8704,42.855999999999995,78.89920000000001,42.855999999999995,78.89920000000001L42.855999999999995,78.928C42.855999999999995,78.928,43.028800000000004,79.5904,43.172799999999995,80.3392L43.6048,82.528L44.007999999999996,84.2848C44.2384,85.408,44.3536,86.2144,44.3536,86.9344C44.3536,87.568,44.2672,88.144,44.1232,88.8064C43.144,92.8096,39.6592,95.2,36.0304,95.2C34.2448,95.2,32.4016,94.624,30.788800000000002,93.328C29.3488,92.11840000000001,28.7152,91.024,28.7152,89.584C28.7152,87.0496,30.759999999999998,85.264,32.8912,85.264C33.64,85.264,34.3888,85.4944,35.1088,85.9264C36.3184,86.7616,36.8656,88.0288,36.8656,89.2672C36.8656,91.168,35.5408,93.03999999999999,33.2656,93.184L33.0352,93.184L33.208,93.2992C34.1584,93.7024,35.1088,93.904,36.0304,93.904C38.3632,93.904,40.552,92.72319999999999,41.8768,90.6784C42.6256,89.5264,43.028800000000004,88.1728,43.028800000000004,86.8192C43.028800000000004,86.3008,42.9424,85.7824,42.827200000000005,85.2064C42.827200000000005,85.1488,42.7408,84.688,42.6256,84.256C41.992000000000004,81.1456,41.617599999999996,79.3312,41.617599999999996,79.3312C41.617599999999996,79.3312,41.617599999999996,79.3312,41.617599999999996,79.3312C41.56,79.3312,41.4448,79.3312,41.3584,79.3888C41.0704,79.4464,40.4656,79.5904,40.2064,79.6192C39.5728,79.7056,38.968,79.7344,38.391999999999996,79.7344C32.7472,79.7344,27.5056,75.9328,25.6912,70.3168C25.2304,68.8192,24.9712,67.3216,24.9712,65.824C24.9712,62.8288,25.9216,59.8912,27.7648,57.2704C29.7808,54.419200000000004,31.7968,51.971199999999996,34.2736,49.436800000000005L35.1376,48.544L34.936,47.4784L34.5616,45.7216L34.072,43.4752C33.928,42.64,33.7552,41.833600000000004,33.7264,41.6608C33.5824,40.7104,33.496,39.7888,33.496,38.8384C33.496,35.2096,34.6768,31.724800000000002,36.8944,28.931200000000004C37.556799999999996,28.0672,38.7376,26.9152,39.0544,26.8288M40.8112,32.5312C40.7536,32.5312,40.6672,32.5312,40.580799999999996,32.5312C39.4,32.5312,37.873599999999996,33.6256,36.8368,35.2384C35.7712,36.8224,35.224000000000004,38.924800000000005,35.224000000000004,41.0848C35.224000000000004,41.6608,35.2528,42.2656,35.3392,42.870400000000004C35.4256,43.302400000000006,35.4544,43.5904,35.684799999999996,44.6272L36.088,46.4416C36.203199999999995,46.9888,36.2896,47.4208,36.2896,47.4784L36.2896,47.4784C36.3184,47.4784,37.2112,46.4992,37.4992,46.1536C40.3792,42.8992,42.1072,39.472,42.4816,36.448C42.510400000000004,36.160000000000004,42.510400000000004,35.9296,42.510400000000004,35.641600000000004C42.510400000000004,34.7488,42.3952,33.8848,42.1936,33.424C41.9632,32.9632,41.4448,32.5888,40.8112,32.5312M36.4624,54.7936C36.4048,54.3904,36.3184,54.0736,36.3184,54.016C36.3184,54.016,36.3184,54.016,36.2896,54.016C36.232,54.016,34.9936,55.456,34.129599999999996,56.464C32.6608,58.2496,31.1056,60.3808,30.472,61.4176C29.2624,63.4624,28.6576,65.7376,28.6576,67.984C28.6576,69.4528,28.9456,70.864,29.464,72.2176C31.019199999999998,76.2208,34.5904,78.7264,38.4784,78.7264C38.9392,78.7264,39.4576,78.6976,39.947199999999995,78.6112C40.580799999999996,78.496,41.3584,78.2656,41.3584,78.1792L41.3584,78.1792C41.3584,78.1792,41.300799999999995,77.8912,41.2144,77.5744L40.3792,73.456L39.7168,70.3744L39.2848,68.2432L38.824,66.1696C38.5936,64.9312,38.5072,64.6144,38.5072,64.6144C38.5072,64.6144,38.5072,64.5856,38.4784,64.5856C38.3056,64.5856,37.384,65.0464,36.9808,65.3344C35.4832,66.3712,34.705600000000004,68.0128,34.705600000000004,69.6256C34.705600000000004,71.152,35.4544,72.6784,36.8944,73.5712C37.2112,73.7728,37.3264,73.9456,37.3264,74.1472C37.3264,74.176,37.3264,74.2624,37.3264,74.2912C37.2688,74.6368,37.0672,74.7808,36.7792,74.7808C36.664,74.7808,36.519999999999996,74.752,36.3472,74.6656C33.6976,73.5136,31.912,70.7776,31.912,67.7824L31.912,67.7824C31.912,64.3264,34.072,61.3312,37.384,60.1504L37.556799999999996,60.0928L37.2688,58.6528L36.4624,54.7936M40.782399999999996,64.4128C40.552,64.384,40.321600000000004,64.384,40.1488,64.384C40.0912,64.384,40.0048,64.384,39.947199999999995,64.384L39.803200000000004,64.384L39.9184,64.9024L40.5232,67.7248L40.8976,69.568L41.300799999999995,71.3824L42.1072,75.3856L42.424,76.912C42.5392,77.3152,42.5968,77.6608,42.6256,77.6608C42.6256,77.6608,42.6256,77.6608,42.6256,77.6608C42.654399999999995,77.6608,43.144,77.3728,43.4608,77.1424C44.9296,76.1056,46.024,74.4928,46.4272,72.8224C46.571200000000005,72.2752,46.6288,71.6992,46.6288,71.152C46.6288,67.8112,44.152,64.7872,40.782399999999996,64.4128" stroke-width="0" font="10pt Arial"></path>
                <path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M64.46065,60M69.47185,41.654399999999995C69.50065000000001,41.625600000000006,69.90385,41.625600000000006,71.14225,41.625600000000006C71.51665,41.625600000000006,71.91985,41.625600000000006,72.43825,41.625600000000006L75.34705,41.625600000000006L75.43345,41.712C75.57745,41.7984,75.66385,41.9424,75.66385,42.0576C75.66385,42.2304,75.57745,42.345600000000005,75.46225,42.4608C75.43345,42.547200000000004,75.17425,42.7776,75.00145,43.0368L73.47505,44.7936L71.51665,47.0112L70.47985,48.192L68.92465,49.9776L66.87985,52.3104C66.53425,52.7424,66.15985,53.088,66.15985,53.088C66.15985,53.088,66.15985,53.088,66.15985,53.088C66.15985,53.1456,66.41905,53.1456,68.80945,53.1456L71.43025,53.1456L71.43025,51.2736C71.43025,49.3728,71.43025,49.344,71.45905,49.315200000000004C71.51665,49.2288,71.77585,48.912,72.78385,47.7312L73.18705,47.2992L73.59025,46.8672L74.19505,46.089600000000004L74.82865,45.4272L75.14545,45.024C75.26065,44.8512,75.43345,44.8224,75.57745,44.8224C75.75025,44.8224,75.89425,44.9088,75.98065,45.052800000000005C76.00945,45.1392,76.00945,45.196799999999996,76.00945,47.328C76.00945,47.8176,76.00945,48.422399999999996,76.00945,49.1424L76.00945,53.1456L76.72945,53.1456C77.39185,53.1456,77.42065,53.1456,77.50705,53.1744C77.73745,53.2608,77.85265,53.4912,77.85265,53.7504C77.85265,53.8944,77.82385,54.0672,77.70865,54.1824C77.53585,54.3264,77.50705,54.3264,76.72945,54.3264L76.00945,54.3264L76.00945,54.816C76.03825,56.2848,76.32625,56.8608,77.44945,57.4656C77.85265,57.6672,77.93905,57.7248,77.93905,58.0128C77.93905,58.2144,77.88145,58.3008,77.73745,58.416L77.65105,58.4448L73.70545,58.4448L69.78865,58.4448L69.70225,58.416C69.52945,58.3008,69.50065000000001,58.2144,69.50065000000001,58.0128C69.50065000000001,57.7248,69.52945,57.6672,69.96145,57.4656C71.08465,56.8608,71.37265000000001,56.2848,71.37265000000001,54.816L71.37265000000001,54.3264L68.06065,54.3264C67.45585,54.384,66.96625,54.384,66.56305,54.384C64.74865,54.384,64.71985000000001,54.3264,64.69105,54.3264C64.51825,54.2688,64.46065,54.096000000000004,64.46065,53.8944C64.46065,53.8944,64.46065,53.8944,64.46065,53.8944C64.46065,53.6928,64.46065,53.6928,65.03665,53.0304C67.45585,50.0928,69.15505,45.8304,69.15505,42.432C69.15505,41.9136,69.24145,41.7408,69.47185,41.654399999999995M71.19985,60.0288L71.22865,60.0288L71.14225,60.0288L71.19985,60.0288M71.19985,40.617599999999996L71.22865,40.617599999999996L71.14225,40.617599999999996L71.19985,40.617599999999996" stroke-width="0" font="10pt Arial"></path>
                <path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M64.46065,80M69.47185,61.654399999999995C69.50065000000001,61.625600000000006,69.90385,61.625600000000006,71.14225,61.625600000000006C71.51665,61.625600000000006,71.91985,61.625600000000006,72.43825,61.625600000000006L75.34705,61.625600000000006L75.43345,61.712C75.57745,61.7984,75.66385,61.9424,75.66385,62.0576C75.66385,62.2304,75.57745,62.345600000000005,75.46225,62.4608C75.43345,62.547200000000004,75.17425,62.7776,75.00145,63.0368L73.47505,64.7936L71.51665,67.0112L70.47985,68.19200000000001L68.92465,69.9776L66.87985,72.3104C66.53425,72.7424,66.15985,73.088,66.15985,73.088C66.15985,73.088,66.15985,73.088,66.15985,73.088C66.15985,73.1456,66.41905,73.1456,68.80945,73.1456L71.43025,73.1456L71.43025,71.2736C71.43025,69.3728,71.43025,69.344,71.45905,69.3152C71.51665,69.2288,71.77585,68.912,72.78385,67.7312L73.18705,67.2992L73.59025,66.8672L74.19505,66.0896L74.82865,65.4272L75.14545,65.024C75.26065,64.8512,75.43345,64.8224,75.57745,64.8224C75.75025,64.8224,75.89425,64.9088,75.98065,65.0528C76.00945,65.1392,76.00945,65.1968,76.00945,67.328C76.00945,67.8176,76.00945,68.4224,76.00945,69.1424L76.00945,73.1456L76.72945,73.1456C77.39185,73.1456,77.42065,73.1456,77.50705,73.1744C77.73745,73.2608,77.85265,73.4912,77.85265,73.7504C77.85265,73.8944,77.82385,74.0672,77.70865,74.1824C77.53585,74.3264,77.50705,74.3264,76.72945,74.3264L76.00945,74.3264L76.00945,74.816C76.03825,76.2848,76.32625,76.8608,77.44945,77.4656C77.85265,77.6672,77.93905,77.7248,77.93905,78.0128C77.93905,78.2144,77.88145,78.3008,77.73745,78.416L77.65105,78.4448L73.70545,78.4448L69.78865,78.4448L69.70225,78.416C69.52945,78.3008,69.50065000000001,78.2144,69.50065000000001,78.0128C69.50065000000001,77.7248,69.52945,77.6672,69.96145,77.4656C71.08465,76.8608,71.37265000000001,76.2848,71.37265000000001,74.816L71.37265000000001,74.3264L68.06065,74.3264C67.45585,74.384,66.96625,74.384,66.56305,74.384C64.74865,74.384,64.71985000000001,74.3264,64.69105,74.3264C64.51825,74.2688,64.46065,74.096,64.46065,73.8944C64.46065,73.8944,64.46065,73.8944,64.46065,73.8944C64.46065,73.6928,64.46065,73.6928,65.03665,73.0304C67.45585,70.0928,69.15505,65.8304,69.15505,62.432C69.15505,61.9136,69.24145,61.7408,69.47185,61.654399999999995M71.19985,80.0288L71.22865,80.0288L71.14225,80.0288L71.19985,80.0288M71.19985,60.617599999999996L71.22865,60.617599999999996L71.14225,60.617599999999996L71.19985,60.617599999999996" stroke-width="0" font="10pt Arial"></path>
                <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" x="20" y="40" width="0.5" height="40.5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" font="10pt Arial"></rect>
                <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" x="0" y="40" width="0.5" height="40.5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" font="10pt Arial"></rect>
                <path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" d="M90,90M97.49664,84.96576C97.7976,84.91104,98.09855999999999,84.91104,98.39952,84.91104C102.7224,84.91104,106.33392,86.82624,106.85376,89.39808C106.88112,89.64432,106.93584,89.8632,106.93584,90.02736C106.93584,92.84544,103.21488,95.11632,98.42688,95.11632C93.63888,95.11632,90,92.79072,90,90.02736C90,89.69904,90.02736,89.37072,90.1368,89.01504C90.79344,86.8536,93.85776,85.18464,97.49664,84.96576M97.90704,85.59504C97.77024,85.56768,97.57872,85.56768,97.44192,85.56768C95.71824,85.56768,94.67856,87.04512,94.67856,88.87824C94.67856,89.8632,94.97952,90.93024,95.6088,91.99728C96.64848,93.63888,98.15328,94.45968,99.4392,94.45968C100.5336,94.45968,101.49119999999999,93.88512,101.92896,92.68128C102.12048,92.1888,102.20256,91.69632,102.20256,91.17648C102.20256,88.71408,100.31472,85.97808,97.90704,85.59504" stroke-width="0" font="10pt Arial"></path>
                <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" x="87" y="90" width="22" height="0.5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" font="10pt Arial"></rect>
                <rect style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;" x="87" y="90" width="22" height="0.5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.3" font="10pt Arial"></rect>
            </svg>
        </canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Hello World
        var score = {"score-partwise":{"$version":"3.0","part-list":{"score-part":[{"$id":"P1","part-name":"Music"}]},"part":[{"$id":"P1","measure":[{"$number":"1","attributes":[{"divisions":"1","key":{"fifths":"0"},"time":{"beats":"4","beat-type":"4"},"clef":{"sign":"G","line":"2"}}],"note":[{"pitch":{"step":"C","octave":"4"},"duration":"4","type":"whole"}]}]}]}};
        var data = new Fermata.Data(score);
        var render = new Fermata.Render(data);
        render.renderAll();
        var drawer = new Fermata.Drawer(data, document.getElementById('canvas-score'));
        drawer.drawAll();
    </script><i title="Raphaël Colour Picker" style="display: none; color: black;"></i> 
</body>
</html>
```

And there is no CSS linked to the page.

Comment: I put your code into a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/mErmF/

Note that I told it to reference Raphael 2.0... if you have to use an earlier version of Raphael for some reason, you can switch it there and see if it still works.

As you can see, it seems to work, there, to some degree (I don't see any bar-lines, for example), so I'm guessing there's something else wrong in your markup and/or includes.

Can you post more of your surrounding HTML? Is your browser throwing any Javascript or loading errors in the console when you try to run your script?

Comment: @mori57: Thank you a lot ! I just edit my post to put all the surrounding code and in fact it don't work in jsFiddle..

Comment: I've never used vexFlow, but an SVG nested in a canvas element seems to indicate that it's a fallback in case `canvas` is not supported. Does it render anything in the canvas?

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing this in? Side-note, but you probably shouldn't name a class and an ID the same thing... in this case, not a biggie (getElementById won't pick up the class name), but in larger apps, it can get confusing.

Comment: Ok thank you again I just changed the canvas tag to a div and it works perfectly ! So obvious i'm a little shameful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was obvious, I put my svg tag inside a canvas tag (I just switched from canvas drawing to svg drawing) and it can't work in any browser.

The answer : Just change the *canvas* tag to a *div* tag and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you! I was experiencing the same problem with invisibile svg in canvas, while still  beeing visible in DOM.  The <canvas> to <div> change did it for me.

Answer (score 12):

If you add SVG elements via JavaScript you must specify namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
for each element.

example

```
 path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
```

Comment: His code works in jsFiddle. I don't know that this answer helps, without more context from the OP about what error(s) his browser is experiencing.

Comment: It seems OK if you create the parent `<svg>` element this way; child elements seem to be addable without needing the `createElementNS`?